# Enable CORS in nodejs with ejs template

Tags: node.js, cors, ejs

I repeatedly receive type errors and empty responses from what may be a CORS issue. I am new to nodejs and am having problems enabling CORS in my application. What is wrong with the following configuration for app.js, where I tried to apply

```
app.all('*',function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

immediately after var app = express();

Here is the full app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

app.all('*',function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});


// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

I consistently receive:

> OPTIONS http://104.236.99.212:6790/ net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
>   undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch(…)

Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your `ExpressJS` app on `node.js`, do the following with your routes:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // Handle the get for this route
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
 // Handle the post for this route
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This turned out to be another issue, but I appreciate the help @Venky